# How do I send a mail in Jenkins whenever a file is added to a particular folder?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am working with Jenkins. Reports are frequently generated by another software and are added to a particular folder which is NOT a part of the workspace in Jenkins. Now whenever a new file is added to the folder, I need to attach this and send out a mail. How do I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple shell script to check if a directory has any new entries of files and if there are new entries trigger a mail and attach the respective file.

This script can be run periodically using cron Jobs.
For sending mails from command line use the following package:-

```
 sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

For mailing through command line info check [this](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html)

```
echo "body of your email" | mail -s "This is a Subject" -a "From: you@example.com" recipient@elsewhere.com
```

Attaching files

```
uuencode surfing.jpeg surfing.jpeg | mail sylvia@home.com
```

Hope it helps.